# Remove Subdatasheet

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a `powerpoint presentation` with `diagrams` where the data of the diagrams are in a `subdatasheet` (the one that opens, when you double click the diagram).

Now I want to send the `presentation` to a customer without the possibility to change the data in the `datasheet` but with the possibility of `animations`.

So just making a pic out of the `diagram` is not an option.

I tried to remove the `linkings` but that did not work. Anyone knows how I can accomplish that on `vba`?

EDIT: 
According to `R3uK's answer` I tried:

```
Sub Export_to_Ppt()
    Dim myChart As PowerPoint.Chart
    Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Diagramm 1").Chart
    myChart.ChartArea.Copy
 ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
End Sub
```

this is working but to me it looks like I get an unanimatable picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this base to export my diagrams in PPT as Office Graphs (`ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`):

```
Sub Export_to_Ppt()
'
Dim Ppt As PowerPoint.Application, _
    Pres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Set Ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set Pres = Ppt.Presentations.Open("C:\Template.potx")

Ppt.Visible = True

Sheets("SubDataSheet").ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

Pres.Slides.Add Index:=Pres.Slides.Count + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutTitleOnly
Pres.Slides(Pres.Slides.Count).Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
Pres.Slides(Pres.Slides.Count).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Chart Title"


Pres.SaveAs _
    Filename:="C:\OutPut_PPT.ppt", _
    FileFormat:=ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation

Set Ppt = Nothing
Set Pres = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still have a question. I adjusted your code (since I am working with powerpoint only) but copied element is a picture and according to my knowledge it is not possible to animate this one. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by Animate? Do you mean set an animation for the picture once it is pasted on the slide? If yes, what kind of animation?

Comment: let us say I have a bubble diagram. I want to fade in each bubble separately.

Comment: Indeed, if it is just a picture, you won't be able to animate it. Once it is pasted with the macro, try to do this manually : select the shape/image, add any animation on it, open Animation Pane, Click on the arrow on the right, Choose Option Effects, On the right tab, you should have lists to select the options of Group : select "One by one" if available. If it is available, it may be programmable (I don't know how but it is probably doable)

Comment: Unfortunately compared to the start diagram there are no options for the copied picture exept for fading the whole thing in and out from left to right (bottom to top) and so on.

Comment: Here are all the options for PasteSpecial : `ppPasteBitmap
ppPasteDefault
ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
ppPasteHTML
ppPasteGIF
ppPasteJPG
ppPasteMetafilePicture
ppPastePNG
ppPasteShape`. I suggest that you try `ppPasteMetafilePicture`, `ppPasteShape` and `ppPasteHTML` to see if can get more from your initial diagram! ;)

Comment: If you paste as enhanced metafile, you'll be able to ungroup the graphic and then select and animate the individual shapes that make up the chart, but since it's no longer a chart, you can't ask PPT to do the heavy lifting for you by animating each series.